# php mysql error on header url for missing DOT before extension

Tags: php, mysql

i need this url return to my main page.... mysite.com
 i use this for empty id or wurl to return to error page

```
if($_GET["wurl"]!=""){
}else{
header("Location: /404NotFound.php");
exit();
}
```

what i do for this url to return to my main page or error page

> http://www.mysite.com/Toni-Michelle-Braxton-4618html

???

Comment: Which url? /404 or the Toni Braxton one? Your question makes very little sense.

Comment: i need this url to goto error page  .. tell me what i do for it

Comment: this url goto to error page
http://www.mysite.com/Toni-Michelle-Braxton-4618html

Comment: @hassan if the url doesn't exist on your server, it'll go to an error page. simple as that. Given the utter lack of detail in your question, that's about all we can say.

Comment: http://www.mysite.com/Toni-Michelle-Braxton-4618html
Toni-Michelle-Braxton-4618 is wurl and and DOT is missing

this url not is fine for me .. i need this URL goto to /404NotFound.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a wild guess and assume the code snippet is your rewriterule handler. (That's what the last comment suggests). If so, then you might already succeed with:

```
if (!strstr($_GET["wurl"], ".html")){   //or just "." instead of ".html"
    exit(header("Location: /404NotFound.php"));
}
```

Try that before your existing `if` block. Should it not work, say so, and someone else can make a lucky code suggestion.

PS: It would be better if you just tested for the existence of the files. (I also surmise you do an unfiltered include there..)

Comment: this will give error in both .html  or witout html
i use like this but not work
if($_GET["wurl"], ".html"!=""){
}else{
header("Location: /404NotFound.php");
exit();
}

Comment: At the very least you should copy the whole code, not just partial excerpts. In particular `strstr()` is not optional for this to work.

Comment: i use your code and replace with my code but in both reason its goto error page .html or without DOT..

Comment: No idea. You should search for a PHP help forum in your native language.

Comment: i didnt like this .. no answer??